# "Why, ..." and "..., why?" meaning

Tags: meaning, books

I'm reading the Brandon Sanderson's Mistborn book to learn English and I wonder why he's using this "Why, ..." and what does it mean

For example:

> "Too proud to crawl?" Kelsier said. "Nonsense! Why, I'd say that we Mistborn are too proud not to be humble..."

Comment: [**why**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/why) ***interjection*** *used to express mild surprise, hesitation, approval, disapproval, or **impatience**.*

Comment: This is **why** used as **interjection**.

Comment: Thank you! But what about "..., why?" pattern?

Comment: Compare>> **Why** are you asking this question of me again? **Why**, I told you I didn't get your explanation.